# Node local server stops instantly as the code does throw err;

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So, in this piece of code I'm trying to use `findOne` to find and delete a particular `dishId` from my `Favorites` document. The code is working fine if I send a valid `dishId` but when I enter a wrong `dishId` the code does `throw err;` and the Node server stops with this error.

> events.js:292
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dishes' of null

And then I've to do `npm start` again. So how should I tackle this? I don't want server to stop. I want it to keep going so that I can do further requests. Here's my code.

```
favoriteRouter.route('/:dishId')
.delete(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, (req,res,next) => {
    Favorites.findOne({user: req.user._id, dishes: req.params.dishId} ,(err, favdel) => {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            favdel.dishes.pull({_id:req.params.dishId});
            favdel.save();
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(favdel);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: you're blindly accessing a property without first checking whether it exists, so: check if `favdel.dishes` exists before you try to get data out of it. And if it doesn't, make [error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) kick in, in a way that makes sure to send the correct HTTP error code.

```
...
            if (!favdel || !favdel.dishes) {
              // only you know which 4xx or even 5xx error this should be
              return next(new Error("..."));
            }
            favdel.dishes.pull({_id:req.params.dishId});
            favdel.save();
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(favdel);
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer solved my issue. Just a little correction, instead of `(!favdel.dishes)` I had to do only `(!favdel)` because that was giving me error `Cannot read property 'dishes' of null`.

Comment: You'll have to do `if (!favdel || !favdel.dishes)` because you _still_ need to check if `.dishes` exists before you access its `pull` function - if you don't, your server might still crash (e.g. there's a db desync and the db returns results, just not with the expected schema)

Comment: Yes, really! I always tend to miss small points. thank you Sir